# In a Kotlin unit test, why does Android Studio show Mockito as unresolved reference EVEN THOUGH it compiles & tests pass?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mockito

Pretty weird problem: Mockito deps *look* broken even though they actually work.

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

[image]

The tooltip over those errors says "unresolved reference".

Some details:

- These are unit tests (under `app/src/test`), not Android instrumentation tests.
- This only happens when the test is **Kotlin**. In equivalent Java test, Mockito deps show up just fine in Android Studio.
- To reiterate, **even though Mockito stuff is shown in red, it still works**: the test  compiles and passes, both on the command line and in Android Studio.

In `build.gradle`, under `dependencies`:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.19.0'

// ... 

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50"
```

(Also I have a file named `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` containing `mock-maker-inline`, [so that Mockito works with final Kotlin classes](https://blog.mindorks.com/mockito-cannot-mock-in-kotlin).)

Edit: This *shouldn't* be relevant, but for Android instrumentation tests, there's also this. (I had some problems updating to Mockito 2 earlier, so sticking with 1.10.19 there.)

```
// Here keeping older Mockito for now 
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
// dexmaker needed for Mockito to work in androidTest
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
```

Using Android Studio 3.5.3

#### What I've tried

- Re-sync the project (`build.gradle`)
- Run `clean` Gradle task inside AS
- Close the project and open it again
- Quit Android Studio completely and open it again

#### Update

I think this is related to **several versions of Mockito** being present in the project.

When I Cmd-click on the names shown in red, it takes me to sources in `mockito-core-1.9.5-sources.jar`; but when I Cmd-click on ArgumentMatchers or MockitoJUnitRunner, it takes me to `mockito-core-2.19.0-sources.jar`, the correct one.

[image]

I investigated with `app:dependencies`, and the only reference to Mockito 1.9.5 is through dexmaker-mockito.

```
+--- com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2
|    +--- com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2
|    \--- org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5 -> 1.10.19 (*)
```

But as dexmaker dependency is only for `androidTest` it *shouldn't* affect anything under `test`, right...?

Edit: indeed, the `androidTest` deps somehow confused Android Studio; commenting out all mockito and dexmaker deps in `androidTestImplementation` removed the faulty error highlights (but as mentioned, the different version was used for a reason).

In the end, [Android Studio update fixed this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61088390/56285).

Comment: How about File -> Invalidate caches & restart ?

Comment: @AlekseyPotapkin: Just tried it, it didn't help either. Thanks though!

Comment: Another interesting detail: ArgumentMatchers and MockitoJUnitRunner are shown without errors, even though they are also part of `mockito-core`.

Comment: I've checked my project and there I use mockitokotlin for kotlin tests and it works fine. You can try it at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well, this was a bug in Android Studio: updating to latest version (3.6.2) fixed it.

The `androidTestImplementation` dependencies were conflicting with `testImplementation` ones; see updated question for details.

Comment: Just ran into this in Android Studio Bumblebee. Had to add Mockito to `androidTestImplementation` as well as `testImplementation`